# Repeated Records in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is there any way to create this type of structure in Java?

In Python it is possible, but we're programming the App Engine in Java and we don't have any idea how to make this.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  Can you give an example?

Comment: I want to create a log structure where for every pair of IDs I save some relevant info (four fields repeating).

Later I'm using this structure of repeating record in Google BigQuery.

Comment: So, are you asking how you can have repeated IDs in, say, a DB table?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `List`:

```
@Cache
@Entity
class  MyClass implements IsSerializable{
    public List<Log> logs;
    ...
```

In your Log class define your 4 fields:

```
@Entity
public class Log  implements IsSerializable {
  public String property1;
  public String property2;
  public String property3;
  public String property4;
  ....
}
```

I assume you are using Objectify

Comment: Thanks for your help, scaevola! We're using Siena but it seems that is not supporting this type of objects.